# Auth.log with hundreds of entries per seconds

Tags: security, debian, authentication, ddos

My Auth.log is becoming super heavy (80G per file) due to constant entries coming from a lot of different IP.

```
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 180.30.141.75:20532: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 217.7.68.178:33733: not enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 217.7.68.178:33733: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 217.7.68.178:33733: next payload type of ISAKMP Message has an unknown value: 76 (0x4c)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 217.7.68.178:33733: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 61.8.76.134:27325: not enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 61.8.76.134:27325: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 103.21.206.53:27430: not enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 103.21.206.53:27430: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 183.108.222.31:40693: not     enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 183.108.222.31:40693: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 219.85.139.163:43305: not enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 219.85.139.163:43305: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 61.8.76.134:45894: next payload type of ISAKMP Message has an unknown value: 30 (0x1e)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 61.8.76.134:45894: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 219.85.139.163:43305: next payload type of ISAKMP Message has an unknown value: 126 (0x7e)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 219.85.139.163:43305: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 124.80.133.178:49554: not enough room in input packet for ISAKMP Message (remain=26, sd->size=28)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 124.80.133.178:49554: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 124.80.133.178:49554: exchange type of ISAKMP Message has an unknown value: 45 (0x2d)
Jun 20 14:00:36 localhost pluto[1796]: packet from 124.80.133.178:49554: Received packet with mangled IKE header - dropped
```

I can't tell if I'm being DDOS or not, and if I am, by which way I can protect myself.

Comment: As an aside, just on the general DDoS mitigation & helping control brute force attacks, you should look at implementing Fail2Ban & Cloudflare - they're both free and easy. Additionally, assuming you haven't got it already, if you're paranoid about your server security, implement IDS, such as OSSEC-HIDS. That's the bare minimum for a secure web facing device imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all IPSec-related traffic. Are you using IPSec? If not, just implement a proper restrictive firewall on inbound traffic and the logs will stop. If you are using IPSec, then perhaps create a firewall whitelist limiting connections to IP addresses you know you will need to accept traffic from.

Comment: Thanks EEAA! I'm not using IPSec. Do you have a good configuration advice for the iptable to target those packets?

Comment: No, but I'm sure there are hundreds of iptables guides online for you to research.